# How to Install and run python and database over busybox

Tags: linux, wifi, python, busybox, sql

I purchased a a WiFi server terminal which runs Busybox and only comes with a http web implementation which pops up once you connect to the WiFi. I'd like to support for SQL (or some variation) and python so i can build in some new web functions over it. Can anyone help break down steps i should take to achieve this? I have no background installing linux packages.

Thanks in advance.